# selected rows from the column as per the values in the rows

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a df as below: where there are 2 columns, student names and marks.

```
Stud_name   Marks
Jon         25
john        20
ajay        50
ram         27
jay         61
jess        46
troy        23
mike        42
steve       45
glenn       43
```

i want few name and their marks.

expected output:

```
Stud_name   Marks
john        20
ajay        50
jess        46
troy        23
ram         27
glenn       43
```

please help.

i tried:

```
pd <- filter(df,Stud_name == "john" , "ajay" , "jess")

Error in filter_impl(.df, quo) : 
Evaluation error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or 
    complex types.
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the selection?

Comment: How should the program decide which lines to return, and how does this differ from the output you are currently getting? Also what code are you using currently?

Comment: no logic just need to get the names and the marks as per the names in the columns as expected output.

Comment: "A few name" as in a sample of your data, using `sample()`?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`, i.e. `filter(df, Stud_name %in% c("john" , "ajay" , "jess"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, if you can think to use a base solution:

```
# your data
dats <- read.table(text='Stud_name   Marks
Jon         25
                   john        20
                   ajay        50
                   ram         27
                   jay         61
                   jess        46
                   troy        23
                   mike        42
                   steve       45
                   glenn       43',sep='', header=T)

# vector with choosen names
names <- c("john","ajay","jess")
dats[which(dats$Stud_name %in% names),]
```

or (thanks @markus):

```
dats[(dats$Stud_name %in% names),]
  Stud_name Marks
2      john    20
3      ajay    50
6      jess    46
```

Comment: Question is about `dplyr::filter` error, not about "show me alternative".

Comment: yeah worked without which. thanks s_t

Comment: Oh, I understood that what OP have tried is with `dplyr::filter`, not that is compulsory. I'll edit the answer, thanks.

Comment: yes i was using dplyr. thanks.